# Seconds elapsed from mysql date entry and now

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have searched,i had too many trial/errors but no luck.So here it goes:

I want to find out how many second have been elapsed since a date from Mysql entry which was inserted with `NOW()` and the current date in the format `date("Y.m.d H:i:s")`.Here is my php function(taken from a user posted @stackoverflow).

```
function multipost(){
global $dbh;
$ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

$sql = "select * from  table where ip='$ipa' order by date_time desc limit 1";

foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    $timeFirst=$row['date_time'];
    $timeSecond=date("Y.m.d H:i:s");
    $differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond-$timeFirst;
    echo $differenceInSeconds;
}
```

I have also tried `strtotime($row['date_time'];)` but no luck.
Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your MySQL Date a DATE format or a DATE TIME format? (MM-DD-YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS) ?

Comment: Trial/error not always good. Better is to get into the know. You can not substract dates as strings in PHP. Please make yourself comfortable with PHP's date and time handling first: http://php.net/datetime - if you are having question about how strings work in PHP, see http://php.net/string

Comment: yeap forgot to mention that mysql date is in 2012-10-30 20:56:42 format YY:MM:DD H:i:s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function secDifference($date,$time){
    $dateVals = explode("-",$date);
    $timeUnix = 0;
    if($time == 0){
        $timeUnix = date("U",mktime(0,0,0,$dateVals[1],$dateVals[2],$dateVals[0]));
    }
    else{
        $tempVals = explode(" ",$dateVals[2]);
        $dateVals[2] = $tempVals[0];
        $timeVals = explode(":",$tempVals[1]);
        $timeUnix = date("U",mktime($timeVals[0],$timeVals[1],$timeVals[2],$dateVals[1],$dateVals[2],$dateVals[0]));
    }
    return (date("U")-$timeUnix);
}
```

Copy this function.
To get difference of DATE and NOW:

```
secDifference("12/03/1993");
```

To get difference of DATE TIME and NOW:

```
secDifference("12/03/1993 14:54:32",1);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did not see your last comment on your question. In that case please use second function call.

Comment: This function is akward. *Shrug* Only you can use it "solve" a problem must not mean you should use it.

Comment: Hey dude I was just trying to find a way to convert dates. It's easy and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can get mysql to return the value for you:

```
select *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), date_time) AS time_diff from  table where ip='$ipa' order by date_time desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know the difference of time in seconds, you can use MySQLs `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` for that. Your query string would look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_time, NOW()) AS time_diff FROM table WHERE ip='$ipa' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 1";
```

**Note** that the return of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is stored as 'time_diff'. Your results will have 'time_diff' as a column added.

For further documentation see [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/date-and-time-functions.html).